# Consume from Restful API with Oauth2 authentication using Go

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

I have an API using Oauth2 authentication and I'm interesting in calling it programmatically with Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("[MY API URL]")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    } else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }
}
```

This returns an http 405 response.

I'm quite new to Go and completely unfamiliar with how to to use restful APIs with Oauth2. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: 405 is `Method Not Allowed`, which means whatever URL you're using for whatever API you're calling doesn't accept `GET` requests.

Comment: You will use the oauth2  module to do the requests https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#NewClient

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez That was really helpful, thanks